# How to remove duplicate alphabets from two strings in java without any builtin functions?

Tags: java, string

Here I have two strings. From that, how can I remove common alphabets/characters and store in result(third) String?

```
<%
    String[] firstString = {"google out"};
    String[] secondString = {"stack overflow"};
    String[] result={""};
        for (int i = 0,k=0; i < firstString.length; i++,k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < secondString.length; j++) {
                if (firstString[i].equalsIgnoreCase(secondString[j])) {
            } else {
                result[k]=result[j]+firstString[i];
                out.println(result[k]);
            }
        }
    }
%>
```

expected result is:
`g l e o u t s c  k v f w`

Comment: Why do you use String array? A string is an array of char, you do not need `String[]` to iterate over characters.

Comment: Also, you're going to need to put bounds on what a "built-in function" is.

Comment: 'l', 'o', 't', 'e' should not be in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach,

```
// Write a static helper method.
public static boolean contains(char[] in, int index, char t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (in[i] == t) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstString = "google out"; // String(s) not String arrays
    String secondString = "stack overflow";
    // output cannot be larger then the sum of the inputs.
    char[] out = new char[firstString.length() + secondString.length()];
    int index = 0;
    // Add all unique chars from firstString
    for (char c : firstString.toCharArray()) {
        if (! contains(out, index, c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    // Add all unique chars from secondString
    for (char c : secondString.toCharArray()) {
        if (! contains(out, index, c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    // Create a correctly sized output array.
    char[] s = new char[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        s[i] = out[i];
    }
    // Just print it.
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}
```

Output is

```
[g, o, l, e,  , u, t, s, a, c, k, v, r, f, w]
```

**Edit**

If your expected output is incorrect, and you actually want the characters that appear in both Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstString = "google out";
    String secondString = "stack overflow";
    char[] out = new char[firstString.length() + secondString.length()];
    int index = 0;
    for (char c : firstString.toCharArray()) {
        if (contains(secondString.toCharArray(), secondString.length(), c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    char[] s = new char[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        s[i] = out[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}
```

Which outputs

```
[o, o, l, e,  , o, t]
```

**Edit 2**

If you actually wanted the opposite of that, change the call to `contains` and add a second loop (for the inverse relationship) -

```
    for (char c : firstString.toCharArray()) {
        if (! contains(secondString.toCharArray(), secondString.length(), c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
    for (char c : secondString.toCharArray()) {
        if (! contains(firstString.toCharArray(), firstString.length(), c)) {
            out[index++] = c;
        }
    }
```

Which will then output

```
[g, g, u, s, a, c, k, v, r, f, w]
```

Comment: 'o', 'l', 't' etc... are present in "gOOgLe OuT" and "sTack OverfLOw", 'l'

Comment: @lpratlong And in the OP's expected output of "g l e o u t s c k v f w".

Comment: @ElliotFrisch So, the best solution should be `return "g l e o u t s c k v f w";` ;). Seriously, I think he made a mistake in his expected output or in his explanation.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Thanks. But I think it's the opposite. He wants chars which appears only in one word. Sorry :).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch You will hate me, but Edit 2 is incomplete I think. You have to check for firstString to secondString and for secondString to firstString. I am absolutly sorry for being such pernickety :).

Comment: @lpratlong Edited again.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to get unique letters can be:

```
String firstString = "google out";
String secondString = "stack overflow";

Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();
Collections.addAll(output, (firstString + secondString).split(""));
```

Output (contains sorted letters with one whitespace in the beginning because it's also unique character):

```
[ , a, c, e, f, g, k, l, o, r, s, t, u, v, w]
```

Comment: Depending on OP's definition of "built-in functions" this *might* not work. Of course, until OP says otherwise, this is a good solution.

Comment: @user3580294 `Collections, Set, HashSet` are built-in in `java.util` package. ;-)

Comment: `String` is also built-in `java.lang` package, so should we use `char` type ?

Comment: But `String` isn't a function (I assume OP means "method"...)

Comment: @hsz But your solution is pretty good. That's a good idea to use Set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other method:

```
private String getUnicChars(String first, String second) {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
                if (!second.contains(String.valueOf(first.charAt(i)))) {
                    result = result + first.charAt(i);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }


  public String yourMethod(String firstString, String secondString) {            
        return getUnicChars(firstString, secondString) + getUnicChars(secondString, firstString);
  }
```

Then you call `yourMethod("google out", "stack overflow");`.

[Actualisation] I assume that you just ask to check redondant char between the two strings but not inside one String. In my solution, the 'g' char will be given twice.[/actualisation]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RoughWork2 {

    // function to remove duplicates first
    public static String removeDuplicate(String val) {

        char[] chars = val.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        for (char c : chars) {
            charSet.add(c);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character character : charSet) {
            sb.append(character);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean sort(String a, String b) {

        String arg1 = removeDuplicate(a);
        String arg2 = removeDuplicate(b);
        if (arg1.length() != arg2.length()) {
            System.out.print("two strings count are not equal");

            return false;
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < arg1.length(); x++) {
                int c = (int) arg1.charAt(x);
                for (int y = 0; y < arg2.length(); y++) {
                    int d = (int) arg2.charAt(y);
                    if (c == d) {

                        System.out.print(Character.toChars(c));
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RoughWork2 rw = new RoughWork2();

        rw.sort("hello", "hallo");

    }
}
```