# Remove common string charaters from a string in java

Tags: java, android, string

Hi I have two strings

```
str1="abcd" 
str2="apcd"
```

Now I want to remove all common characters from the second string. How can I do this? I tried it with `HashSet` but is there any simple way? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post example code of what you've tried that doesn't work, or point out where in your code you think it's overly complex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate alphabets from two strings in java without any builtin functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783710/how-to-remove-duplicate-alphabets-from-two-strings-in-java-without-any-builtin-f)

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one line with `String#replaceAll`. You use the first string between brackets as the regex to match against. This works because `[abc]` matches `a`, `b` or `c`.

```
public static String removeCommon(String string1, String string2) {
    return string2.replaceAll("[" + string1 + "]", "");
}
```

**Example code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeCommon("abcd", "apcd"));
}
```

**Output**

```
p
```

Comment: That was a clever response

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("abcd");
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("apcd");

for(int i=0;i<sb1.length();i++){            
    for(int j=0;j<sb2.length();j++){                    
        if(sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j)){
        sb2.deleteCharAt(j);                        
        }                   
    }           
}
System.out.println(sb2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using Guava:

```
package org.example;
import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
public class CharRemover {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String str1 = "abcd";
    final String str2 = "apcd"; 
    System.out.println(CharMatcher.anyOf(str1).and(
                       CharMatcher.anyOf(str2)).removeFrom(str2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if my answer is wrong.
Because i am new to java.

```
public class Stack {
static int count=0;
static int index=0;
public static void main(String args[])
{
String  str1="abcdg"; 
String  str2="apcdj";

int i=0;
char buffer[]=new char[str1.length()];
        for(i=0;i<str1.length();i++)
        {
            char s=str1.charAt(i);
            char s1=str2.charAt(i);
            if(s!=s1)
            {
                int j=i;
                j=i-count;
                buffer[j]=s1;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        str2=String.valueOf(buffer);
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
```

}